# Flutter GridView with Header

Tags: gridview, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-sliver, flutter-appbar

How to create the grid view with scrollable toolbar in FLUTTER. I have found the list view with header [ListViewWithHeader](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/lists/mixed-list). But I need the GridView with header like in the mentioned image below.I have used SilverGrid ignorer to build this layout, which is little laggy. So I need another option.

[image]

```
Container setDataToContainer() {
  return Container(
    color: Colors.white,
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 4.0, right: 4, bottom: 4, top: 4),
    child: CustomScrollView(
      slivers: <Widget>[
        SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
            [
              HeaderWidget("Header 1"),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        SliverGrid(
          gridDelegate:
              SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
          delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
            [
              BodyWidget("title", "key_x", "pnl.svg"),
              BodyWidget("title2", "key_x", "cls.svg"),
              BodyWidget(
                  "title3", "key_x", "irr.svg"),
              BodyWidget(
                  "title4", "key_x", "icp.svg"),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
            [
              HeaderWidget("Header 2"),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        SliverGrid(
          gridDelegate:
              SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
          delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
            [
              BodyWidget("title5", "key_x", "ict.svg"),
              BodyWidget("title6", "key_x", "icc.svg"),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
            [
              HeaderWidget("Others"),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        SliverGrid(
          gridDelegate:
              SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
          delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
            [
              BodyWidget("title7", "key_x", "icd.svg"),
              BodyWidget("title8", "6", "ici.svg"),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}

class HeaderWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;

  HeaderWidget(this.text);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10, bottom: 2, top: 20),
      child: Text(
        text.toUpperCase(),
        style: TextStyle(
            color: hexToColor(themeColor1),
            fontSize: 16,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      ),
      color: Colors.white,
    );
  }
}

class BodyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String imagePath;
  final String title;
  final String navigationKey;

  BodyWidget(this.title, this.navigationKey, this.imagePath);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Card(
          color: hexToColor(themeColor1),
          elevation: 5,
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              navigateToView(context, navigationKey);
            },
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                  child: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
                    child: SvgPicture.asset(
                      "assets/images/$imagePath",
                      color: Colors.white,
                      width: 35,
                      height: 35,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                    verticalDirection: VerticalDirection.up,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(.2),
                        child: Text(
                          title,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 14,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }

  void navigateToView(BuildContext context, String navigationKey) {

    Navigator.push(
      context,
      PageRouteBuilder(
        pageBuilder: (context, animation1, animation2) {
          return NewSections();
        },
        transitionsBuilder: (context, animation1, animation2, child) {
          return FadeTransition(
            opacity: animation1,
            child: child,
          );
        },
        transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 600),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you tried sticky_headers plugin for that

Comment: No I didn't. I want to replace SliverGrid with another option cause it's little laggy in my case.

Comment: Hi @jazzbpn, Im facing the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: You could write your header texts using `SliverToBoxAdapter` instead of a `SliverList` with one child!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try the [sticky_headers](https://pub.dev/packages/sticky_headers) plugin instead of SliverGrid

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sticky_headers/sticky_headers.dart';

class GridHeader extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GridHeaderState createState() => _GridHeaderState();
}

class _GridHeaderState extends State<GridHeader> {

  List<String> listHeader = ['HEADER1','HEADER2','HEADER3','HEADER4','HEADER5','HEADER6','HEADER7','HEADER8','HEADER9','HEADER10',];
  List<String> listTitle = ['title1','title2','title3','title4',];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Grid Header Demo"),
      ),
      body: gridHeader(),
    );
  }


  Widget gridHeader(){
    return ListView.builder(itemCount: listHeader.length,itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return StickyHeader(
        header: new Container(
          height: 38.0,
          color: Colors.white,
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12.0),
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: Text(listHeader[index],
            style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.purple, fontSize: 20,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
        ),
        content: Container(
          child: GridView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            itemCount: listTitle.length,
            gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2,childAspectRatio: 1,),
            itemBuilder: (contxt, indx){
              return Card(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                color: Colors.purpleAccent,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 12.0, top: 6.0, bottom: 2.0),
                  child: Center(child: Text(listTitle[indx], style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.black54),)),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
      shrinkWrap: true,
    );
  }
}
```

Change your  `listHeader` and `listTitle` data according to your requirement

Comment: The image is reloading every time when I scroll. How can I handle this?

Comment: local, from assets folder.

Comment: if your are using like CachedNetworkImage and precacheImage, then try the Image.asset(" ") for the local image

Comment: Yeah I tried that but it's still laggy. Every time I scroll the items reload again and again.

Answer (score 0):

Here I've created [flat_list](https://pub.dev/packages/flat_list) widget which has similar specifications as in React Native's FlatList. Hope the below works.

```
FlatList(
+  numColumns: 2,
+  listHeaderWidget: const Header(),
  data: items.value,
  buildItem: (item, index) {
    var person = items.value[index];

    return ListItemView(person: person);
  },
),
```